# Measuring Performance of a java algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, testing

How can i measure the performance of my java algorithm effectively ? is there any accurate way of doing it?

i read other questions of same kind but not satisfied.
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What would you like to measure? Time complexity?

Comment: You might find [Caliper](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/) useful.

Comment: i have eclipse....through code also i am ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some profilers. Many IDEs (such as Netbeans) have one.

Comment: There is a sollution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713940/eclipse-java-profiler I am not using eclipse. But measuring system time may givu you bad results. Becouse your process can be paused. You need time used by your process.

Comment: Yes i need to run a profiler for my eclipse too. I have the latest version of eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

```
long reference=System.nanoTime();
your_funct();
long finishm=System.nanoTime();

System.out.println( ( (double)(finishm-reference) )/1000000000.0);  //in seconds
```

Has a meaningful level of ~0.003 seconds in my machine. I mean, you measure in nano-seconds but smallest step is around 3000000 nanoseconds in my machine.

Comment: That works really badly in practice - for example it doesn't allow the JIT compiler to run. It is hard to do this right, especially for Java. See eg http://www.azulsystems.com/presentations/art-of-java-benchmarking.

Comment: If you can print the resulting-time of a very exhausting calculation-sequence from console in real-time, you can see in real-world

Answer (score 3):

You ask for performance which indicates some sort of timing.  But then what would you compare against?

A general way of measuring an algorithm is using Big O, which takes a simplified mathematical approach.

To explain this at a very basic level a simple linear search of a list of integers has a linear (n) worst case big o.  Eg:
for(int i = 0; i < sizeofarray; ++i)
  if(array[i] == to_find)
     return i;

At the worst case this would take i iterations (often number is referred to as n in big o) - so we call it n or linear complexity algorithm.

Something like a bubblesort algorithm is a loop within a loop so we have n * n complexity = n^2 or quadratic complexity.

Comparing like with like, if we just consider sorting, quicksort is more efficient than quadratic complexity (it is n log n complexity) so you can consider quicksort being 'better' than bubblesort.

So when evaluating your algorithm think about it in terms of n.  Is there a loop?  how many?  The fewer the better.  No loops even better - constant big o.

Answer (score 2):

If can make it practical or theoretical. If practical then put a timer before the algorithm starts and stop it when it ends. If theoretical then use [Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) (isn't that hard) and you'll get an estimate of its time or space complexity.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is still java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis() as it will work regardless the IDE you are using.